# Event before 'load event' for Firefox extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, firefox-addon, dom-events

I'm writing a Firefox extension,

This is my XUL (no problem there)

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE overlay SYSTEM "chrome://locale/myDtd.dtd">
<page id="overlay" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"
         xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <script type="application/x-javascript" src="chrome://addon/content/test.js" />
</page>
```

And here is the problematic part of the Javascript test.js

```
window.addEventListener("load",
    function(event) {
        var appcontent = window.document.getElementById("appcontent");
        appcontent.addEventListener("load",onEventLoad,true);
    }, true);
```

The second 'load' listener on appcontent is too slow for my needs.
The 'load' event is triggered when the DOM is done loading.

**My question:** Does anyone have an idea of how to run code as soon as a document starts loading (before the load event of the DOM) ? (wish a onBeforeLoad or onRequestStart event existed)

In Chrome extensions, we can use "run_at": "document_start" in 'manifest.json',
and in Safari extensions, we can use 'Starting script' in extension builder
but in Firefox ... I don't know how to do the same trick.

I need this to start looking at elements in the DOM as soon as they arrive (but that's another story).

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3):

There's a good explanation here:

http://blog.webmynd.com/2011/04/04/equivalent-to-beforeload-event-for-firefox-extensions/

The suggested solution relies on Firefox Observers and http-on-modify-request:

```
Components.classes["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"]
  .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIObserverService)
  .addObserver({
    observe: function(aSubject, aTopic, aData) {
      if ("http-on-modify-request" == aTopic) {
        var url = aSubject
          .QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIHttpChannel)
          .originalURI.spec;
        if (url && url.match('facebook')) {
          aSubject.cancel(Components.results.NS_BINDING_SUCCEEDED);
        }
    }
  }
}, "http-on-modify-request", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you take var appcontent = `window.document.getElementById("appcontent");` out of the eventlistener and do a setInterval until it actually sees that DOM element get populated?

```
init();

function init(){
    var intval = setInterval ( "checkForElement()", 200 );
}

function checkForElement(){
    if (document.getElementById('appcontent') != 'undefined'){
        clearInterval(intval);
        var appcontent = window.document.getElementById("appcontent");
        appcontent.addEventListener("load",onEventLoad,true);
    }
}
```

You might have to do some `alert(document.getElementById('appcontent'));` debugging to see if each browser treats a null element the same way.

Comment: appcontent is there from the beginning, so the interval here is not helping. The problem is that i need to detect the document that starts loading, so I could wait for element in it. The thing is that I access the document throught the event catched by the appcontent.addEventListener and that event is triggered by the 'load' event that comes too late.

Comment: So, 'appcontent' is an element in your extension? and when you say document, you are referring to the target web page that you will be affecting with a content-script method? (Sorry for the terminology, i am usually a chrome developer).

If this is the case... can you replace 'appcontent' in the js with the target element in the document? and then let the interval sit and wait for that?

Comment: appcontent is the XUL for the extension. It is needed to grab the document from the event.target generated from it. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/On_page_load

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the `src` of your appcontent element as an attribute in the XUL source code? That makes things tricker, as XUL doesn't like you accessing elements while it's loading. What you could try is adding a derived XBL binding to the element, and defining a capturing event handler there. Or you might find that the `DOMContentLoaded` event is early enough. Otherwise I would suggest leaving the appcontent element blank and only loading it after you've added your load event handler in the main window's load event handler.

Comment: The only thing I do with the appcontent is to attach eventListener so I can catch the load event.

Comment: I think about using ProgressListener, so I can start processing as soon as the url changes. 'Components.interfaces.nsIWebProgressListener'