# Expose js variable from firefox addon

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I have to build a firefox extension and I want to be able to find if the extension is installed from any website using js.

I tried just setting a boolean on the extension code like:

```
myExtensionName_is_installed = true;
```

But that wont work, I don't have access to that from js. Some extensions like firebug has functions that one can use from js like console.log(), so how can I make my extension boolean to be available from any website using js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention all too many details but I guess that the problem is [XPCNativeWrappers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCNativeWrapper) - your code and the webpage have different views of the DOM, properties you add to DOM objects usually aren't visible to web pages. If you want to set a variable on the `window` object and have the window see it you need to do it like this:

```
XPCNativeWrapper.unwrap(window).myExtensionName_is_installed = true;
```

As to how you would get to a `window` object - classic extensions would [use `content-document-global-created` notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292511/how-to-manipulate-window-prototype-in-a-browser-element/8293541#8293541). Extensions built with the Add-on SDK would [use `page-mod` package](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8874858/785541) (there you have `unsafeWindow` property and don't need to unwrap the window object explicitly).

Answer (score 0):

I would inject some identifying element into the page using your extension. Then use browser side javascript to see if it exists.

```
<div id="myext" style="display: none;">MyExtension v2.x</div>

if (document.getElementById('myext').length > 0) { ... }
```

Comment: But wouldn't I have to wait until everything is loaded to be able to detect that element? I'd prefer to be able to detect if it's installed before the document is ready.

Comment: I imagine FF has a way for extensions to trigger earlier in the process. I found this SO question regarding it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330048/event-before-load-event-for-firefox-extension